# how can i receive json as body in spring controller?

Tags: json, ajax, spring, controller

I wonder.

 `{
  "name":"test",
  "age":"123"
 }`

String name, String age When I get this, its values ​​will be null.

Generally, do we create a domain or bean ? Or is there only a way to get it with a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, Map is not the only way to get it. You can make a class and receive it by `@RequestBody`**

Class

```
public class Something {
  String name;
  String age;
  // getter, setter and constructor
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST )
   @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.CREATED )
   @ResponseBody
   public Long create( @RequestBody Something something ){
      .....
      return someLongValue;
}
```

You can get detail example from [here](http://www.baeldung.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-and-java-based-configuration)

Comment: Is there a way to always create a bean like above? 
Should I then create a bean for each controller?
This seems to be too inefficient.

Comment: It is your choice whether you create class for each controller or use Map. I would rather use map for this type of two parameters(your case). Whether you write the parameter names and types wherever just one time, isn't equal to write a class at once? doesn't seems inefficient. more it will be structured if you reuse.

Comment: Just only Map convert create json same.

Comment: I have to think more. Thank you anyway.